# How to handle angular 5 recursive unknown exact number router parameters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, frontend

Is there a way to handle recursively unknown exact number of router parameters?

**For example:**

We have products categories, which can have subcategories, subcategories can have it's own subcategories and so on. There are a few main conditions:

- if a such category has no subcategories we redirect to `/categories/{id}/items` that will open items list component.
- if category has subcategory it should be redirected to next nested tree level `/categories/{id}/{id}/.../{id}` which should open the last categoryId subcategories list component.
- after getting to the last category which doesn't has subcategories items list component will be shown `/categories/{id}/{id}/.../{id}/items`.

The solutions to check  and redirect is to have router resolver. But how track those urls in routing module ?

From my perspective the routes should look something like this:

```
{
  path: '/categories/:id',
  component: SubcategoriesListComponent
},
{
  path: '/categories/:id/**/:id',
  component: SubcategoriesListComponent,
},
{
  path: '/categories/:id/**/:id/items',
  component: CategoryItemsListComponent
}
```

Is it possible implement it in a such way ?

Comment: I had written a blog post which could answer this question 
https://techblog.tabrezahmed.com/recursive-routes-in-angular-ck37hknlk00tyb6s1cqp8sby5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible solution with componentless routes: 
in routes config

```
{
    path: 'categories/:id', children: [
    {path: '**', component: SubcategoriesListComponent}
]
}
```

in component file:

```
export class SubcategoriesListComponent {

  constructor(aroute: ActivatedRoute) {
    aroute.url.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('params ', data); //contains all the segments so put logic here of determining what to do according to nesting depth
    });

  }

}
```

Here is the [output example](http://prntscr.com/if3t84) (i tested on my project ErrorComponent so don't be confused)

Comment: It didn't solve my problem completely, but for this specific case helped a lot.
Thank you!