# File System Simulation with Angular Router

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing

I am Trying to simulate a file system on the webapp made with Angular.

Lets say I got a fileExplorer.component that displays the file system.

I want to display this same component for every routes. 
For example.

```
{
  path: 'file-explorer',
  component: fileExplorerComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: '/deep',
      component: fileExplorerComponent
      children: [
        {
          path: '/deeper',
          component: fileExplorerComponent
          children: [
            {
              path: '/deepest',
              component: fileExplorerComponent
            },
            {
              path: '/deepest2',
              component: fileExplorerComponent
            },
            {
              path: '/deepest3',
              component: fileExplorerComponent
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          path: '/deeper2',
          component: fileExplorerComponent
        },
        {
          path: '/deeper3',
          component: fileExplorerComponent
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/deep1',
      component: fileExplorerComponent
    },
    {
      path: '/deep2',
      component: fileExplorerComponent
    }
  ]
}
```

But This can go as long as 10 levels deep or it can be even one single level deep.

The problem is I want to maintain the route information as well.

How do i solve this problem ?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807518/how-to-handle-angular-5-recursive-unknown-exact-number-router-parameters/48808565#48808565

Comment: That does help but I still couldnt get the final result.  

Will try to get it from that logic