# ActivatedRoute subscribe to first child parameters observer

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

I'm  not sure if this is the best way to implement this. If you have other opinions please share.

I have to implement a multi inbox system where the user can have multiple emails grouped by different inboxes.

For example: `http://localhost/inbox/personal/` will show a list of emails in `personal` inbox, `http://localhost/inbox/business/3` will show a list of emails in `business` inbox and will highlight email with id: `3`

Routes look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'personal' // redirect to personal inbox
  },
  {
    path: ':inbox',
    component: InboxContentComponent, // list of emails in :inbox
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: InboxNoSelectedEmailComponent, // no email selected
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: InboxSelectedEmailComponent, // show selected email content
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

My problem is with `InboxContentComponent` . I need to detect when inbox changes and if an email is selected or not

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(inbox => {
      console.log('inbox', inbox);
    });
  }
```

Events are emitted only when inbox changes and not when email changes. 
Is there a way to detect when child route parameters changes?

Doing this `this.route.firstChild.paramMap.subscribe();` only works if on component initialization the route has a first child. if the route is like this `http://localhost/inbox/business/` then `this.route.firstChild` is `null`

On solution I could think is to define routes like this

```
{
    path: ':inbox/:id',
    component: InboxContentComponent
}
```

and then check in `InboxContentComponent` if `:id` is set or not

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this answer will provide you possible solution idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48807518/how-to-handle-angular-5-recursive-unknown-exact-number-router-parameters/48808565?noredirect=1#comment84654490_48808565

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To tackle this kind of problem, I would listen to router events and retrieve what I want. Something like this :

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, map, mergeMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...
constructor(
    // ...
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.activatedRoute),
      map((route) => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      }),
      mergeMap((route) => route.paramMap),
      tap(
        paramMap => console.log('ParamMap', paramMap)
      )
    ).subscribe(
      (paramAsMap) => // Get the params (paramAsMap.params) and use them to highlight or everything that meet your need 
    )
  }
```

You can adapt this to your need. Params ? Highlight : NoHighlight.

Comment: When attempting the above with Angular 10, tslint says:
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'

Comment: Hi mickdev, could you please explain the `while(route.firstChild) route= route.firstChild` part of your answer? I am not sure I get it

Comment: hey @DarioPiotrowicz, did you get it? I am interested in getting it too :p

Comment: Hey @IraklisBekiaris sorry for the late reply, I think I get it, basically if you have multiple child routes (so multiple `router-outlet`s), you may need to "drill down" to the route you are interested in, have a look at this stackblitz I made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tudm6k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts there you can see when you click the link what this whole while-firstChild loop actually does. I hope this helps :)